# Azure devops page conflict

Tags: azure-devops

2 developers are updating the same file in the same project. the last update gives an error. Because the first updated codes are not found in the file that the 2nd developer is trying to update. Migrate error.
This way, the first updated user's codes are deleted. How can I solve this problem?

Azure devops Repos style.css

```
a{}b{}
```

1. Developer's style.css (First updater)

   `a{}b{}c{}d{}`

2.Developer's style.css

```
a{}b{}e{}
```

updated Azure devops repos style.css

```
a{}b{}e{}
```

c{} and d{} disappeared

Comment: Hi Furkan. What does "Migrate Error" mean and where/when does 2nd developer see that? Also, "Repos style.css" seems to imply an underlying Git repository. Is that so? It sounds as though the 2nd developer would be responsible for resolving this (upon Repo pull), before checking in their code. However, I am guessing at significant details.

Comment: Two developers are also developing in the Azure DevOps master git repository. The Problem is that two users are updating the day morning with the master version of the style. css file. At the end of the Day, a developer is uploading his changes to the master. Then The other developer is doing the update. But because he was unaware of the first update, something like that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your team needs to select and adhere to a version control workflow that meets your needs and that is supported by [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) (the distributed source control you have ***apparently*** chosen). I suggest starting here: [Azure Repos Git tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitworkflow?view=azure-devops).

You might even question whether [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) is the appropriate source control choice given your needs. See [Choosing the right version control for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops)

Comment: For what it's worth Yiğit san, I advise you to continue using Git. It almost certainly meets your needs and distributed source control provides added flexibility. However, again, you and your team must select and adhere to a supported workflow.